# additional help Northwind Example SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having, northwind

I have question about the `Northwind` SQL Server sample database that I don't know how to solve it

Show `CustomerID` for all customers who have at least three different products from all orders, but never ordered 2 products from the same category.

i didn't know how to check "but never ordered 2 products from the same category"

please help me :)
  Code I tried for this question:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerID,COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID)
FROM 
    Customers c
JOIN 
    Orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN 
   [Order Details] od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
JOIN 
   Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
GROUP BY
   c.CustomerID
HAVING
   COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) >= 3
```

I've been stuck on these query for hours, please help guys!

This is link for `Northwind` sample database: https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more condition to check if the number of distinct products equal the number of distinct categories. This makes sure that there is always one and only one product from each category.

```
SELECT 
c.CustomerID,COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID), count(distinct c.categoryid)
FROM Customers c
JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Details] od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID) >= 3 
and count(distinct c.categoryid) = COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductID)
```

Comment: hi @vkp
 sorry , was mistake on the question.. the correct one is: "but never ordered 2 products from the same category

Comment: yes that means that there can only be one product from each category.

Comment: but if i do like u said and there was 2 categories so i need remove both and not keep one (distanct) ,  no?

Comment: it would help if you could post sample data and the desired results. even better if you could set up a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If each order must be from a different category, then COUNT(product) should be the same as COUNT(category). That's one way to logically approach it, but no doubt there are other solutions.

Comment: hi @Stidgeon , sorry , was mistake on the question..
the correct one is: "but never ordered 2 products from the same category."